# From TopLeft 0,0 to BottomLeft 0,0 in GDI win32

Tags: winapi, coordinate-systems

How can I change transform the coordinates in a window from 0,0 topleft to 0,0 bottomleft.

I have tried various solutions with
`SetMapMode(hdc,MM_TEXT);`,
`SetViewportExtEx(hdc,0,-clientrect.bottom,NULL);`
`SetViewPortOrgEx(hdc,0,-clientrect.bottom,NULL);`
`SetWindowOrgEx(hdc,0,-clientrect.bottom,NULL);`
`SetWindowExtEx(hdc,0,-clientrect.bottom,NULL);`
I have even tried google for a solution but to no prevail, so I turn to you the more experienced people on the internet.

The idea is I'm creating a custom control for linear interpolation and I could reverse the coordinate system by x,y in top right corner but I want it right. At the moment I get a reversed linear interpolation when I try to draw it as I cannot get the coords to be bottomleft.

I'm using win32 api, and I suspect I can skip the code as the screen coordinate system is almost identical on all systems, by that I mean 0,0 is "always" topleft on the screen if you are keeping it to standard 2d window and frames.

I really don't want a whole codesample to ease the typing pain for you guys, but I want some direction as it seems I cannot grasp the simple concept of flipping the coords in win32 api.

Thanks and a merry christmas

EDIT !

I would like to add my own answer to this question as I used simple math to reverse the view so to say.

If for an example I got the valuepair x,y (150,57) and another pair x,y (100,75) then I used this formulae `height + (-1 * y)` and voila I get a proper cartesian coordinate field :) ofcourse in this example height is undefined variable but in my application its 200px in height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation for [SetViewportOrgEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145099%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you generally want to use it or `SetWindowOrgEx`, but not both. That said, you probably want the viewport origin to be `(0, clientrect.bottom)`, not `-clientrect.bottom`.

Setting transforms with GDI always made me crazy. I think you're better off using GDI+. With it, you can create a matrix that describes a translation of `(0, clientRect.bottom)`, and a scaling of `(1.0, -1.0)`. Then you can call `SetWorldTransform`.

See the example at [Using Coordinate Spaces and Transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145174%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). For general information about transforms: [Coordinate Spaces and Transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183475%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Additional information:

I've not tried this with direct Windows API calls, but if I do the following in C# using the `Graphics` class (which is a wrapper around GDI+), it works:

```
Graphics g = GetGraphics();  // gets a canvas to draw on
SetTranslateTransform(0, clientRect.Bottom);
SetScaleTransform(1.0f, -1.0f);
```

That puts the origin at the bottom left, with `x` increasing to the right and `y` increasing as you go up. If you use `SetWorldTransform` as I suggested, the above will work for you.

If you have to use GDI, then you'll want to use `SetViewportOrgEx(0, clientRect.bottom)`, and then set the scaling. I don't remember how to do scaling with the old GDI functions.

Note also that the [documentation for SetViewportExtEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145098%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says:

> When the following mapping modes are set, calls to the SetWindowExtEx
>   and SetViewportExtEx functions are ignored.
>
> - MM_HIENGLISH
> - MM_HIMETRIC
> - MM_LOENGLISH
> - MM_LOMETRIC
> - MM_TEXT
> - MM_TWIPS

Comment: I should have mentioned that I tried severeal solutions not just both at the same, but I did try both. By using your solution I would still have a problem that I need to negate all the values to go upwards, therefor I used -clientrect.bottom, as I understood from MSDN.

Comment: Thank you Jim Mischel, I will continue my tedious hard stupid idea, as it should be working. I will not use GDI+ as I'm stubborn and will shot myself in the foot, to be honest :) Have a merry christmas.